Units of the action of a charged particle in four-potential coupling
I have a question about the definition of the action that Landau defines as:
\begin{equation}
S= -\frac{e}{c}\int A^{\mu}dx_{\mu} 
\end{equation}
he says that the $1/c$ factor is introduced by convenience. My question relates only to the dimensional analysis of the spatial part, because i'm basically doing this:
\begin{equation}
\frac{e}{c}A^idx_i\equiv \frac{[C][T]}{[L]}\cdot\frac{[V][T]}{[L]}\cdot[L] =
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\frac{[C][T]}{[L]}\cdot\ \frac{[U][T]}{[C]}=\frac{[U][T]^2}{[L]}
\end{equation}
where $[U]\equiv j~(joules)$, $[C]\equiv (coulomb)$. I can't see how the action could have units of $\textbf{energy x time}$. I missing some basic concept of dimensional analysis? I even thought about canceling [T] and [L] since the context is relativistic, but that should cause a "$c$" to appear.

Doesn’t Landau use Gaussian units rather than SI? If so, $A^0$ is the electric potential $\varphi$, $e\varphi$ is energy, and $dx_0/c$ is $dt$. Surely the spatial components give the same result!

if i use SI the factor 1/c isn't even necessary, becouse in the SI system $A^{\mu}=(\phi/c,\vec{A})$ then both components are correct. But he used the definition in the gaussian system, then $A^{\mu}=(\phi,\vec{A})$, so when introducing the factor 1/c the temporal components are correct but the spatial seems like are not. I'm confused because after this then he sum this term to the free action $S=mc\int ds$ whose units seem to be correct.

In Gaussian units, $[e]=[M]^{1/2}[L]^{3/2}[T]^{-1}$ and $[\vec A]=[M]^{1/2}[L]^{1/2}[T]^{-1}$ so $[e\vec A]=[M][L]^2[T]^{-2}=[E]$. And $[dx/c]=[T]$, so everything works just fine.

Thank you very much, i was really mixing up some units with dimensions. I think i need to revise these things kkkk.
